# Best way to package large numbers of large files for download?

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I have an ASP.NET website that stores large numbers of files such as videos. I want an easy way to allow the user to download all the files in a single package. I was thinking about creating ZIP files dynamically.

All the examples I have seen involve creating the file before it is downloaded but potentially terabytes of information will be downloaded and therefor the user will have a long wait. Apparently ZIP files store all the information regarding what is in the ZIP file at the end of the file.

My idea is to dynamically create the file as its downloaded. This way I could allow the user to click download. The download would start and not require any space on the server to be pre packaged as it would copy things over uncompressed sequentially. The final part of the file would contain the information on the contents of what has been downloaded.

Has anyone had any experience of this? Does anyone know a better way of doing this? At the moment I cant see any pre made utilities for doing this but I believe it will work. If it doesn't exist then i'm thinking that I will have to read the Zip file format specifications and write my own code... something that will take more time than I was intending to spend on this.

https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Comment: [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the link but GZip would require packaging all the files first in a single location. If I have Terabytes of information then I cant guarantee there will be enough memory in RAM or on the hard drive to do that. It would also be slow... or am I miss interpreting that?

Comment: Why not store them on the server compressed in the first place? Videos are already fairly compressed (depending on the compression used), so zipping them may not give any (or much) size advantage unless it is raw video. The issue with compressing "on the fly" is that usually you have to build your compression by going through the entire file. You could compress it in chunks, but again, if it is video/audio it is probably about as compressed as it is going to get.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. I'm  not interested in the compression. What I'm interested in is packaging all the files into a single zip file so they can easily be downloaded